# Maven Multi Module Hot deploy in Jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, hotdeploy

We have a multi-module maven project, which has to be deployed in Jboss 7.1.1 server. It takes most of our time redeploying for code changes. Have seen to use Jrebel for hot deployment, but the expense will not meet to us with 20 developers.

So is there any workaround for hot deployment of maven-multi-module project in Jboss?

Here is build configuration of our project in POM:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.0.Beta1b</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <port>9999</port>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.ear</filename>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```